# Insert multiple rows in a table using a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm trying to get all the items of the cart_items and add it to the ticket_items.
I've the error "SUBQUERY RETURN MULTIPLE ROWS", but that's what I want, insert all that rows in the ticket_items table in a same query.

```
INSERT INTO ticket_items (ticket_id, ISBN, quantity) 
VALUES (
    (SELECT COUNT(ticket_id) FROM ticket), 
    (SELECT ISBN FROM cart_items WHERE customer_id = 1),
    (SELECT quantity FROM cart_items WHERE customer_id = 1)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using an aggregate function (`COUNT`) that will build exactly one value, but both isbn and quantity occur twice or more. So, the insert that will be built by your query is something like

```
INSERT INTO ticket_items (ticket_id, ISBN, quantity) 
VALUES (10, 1,2,3, 4,5,6);
```

This is of course not allowed. Since you do a `COUNT`, you need to apply `GROUP BY` to create multiple rows which will be inserted.
So your insert command will be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ticket_items (ticket_id, ISBN, quantity) 
((SELECT COUNT(ticket_id), ISBN, quantity
FROM ticket, cart_items
WHERE customer_id = 1
GROUP BY ISBN, quantity));
```

This will work correctly and do what you asked for, I created an example here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5a4b6c4426d971e3aef114513f75365e)

You should check if this is really what you want because for me, it doesn't make sense to insert the count of ticket_id like you describe. But this is something you must check on your own.

Comment: Thank!, it's exactly how it assumes it should work. I had already implemented it, but your logic is much more efficient. :D

Answer (score 0):

Don't use VALUES keyword.

**Please see syntax below:**

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

I would first make sure that select gives you the expected result, then issue the insert statement.

Upon review, I believe the issue is with SELECT part.
You should rewrite it  as one SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO ticket_items (ticket_id, ISBN, quantity) 
(SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(ticket_id) from ticket) as ticket_id, ISBN, quantity
FROM  cart_items
WHERE customer_id = 1)
```

Good luck!

Comment: I would use that if I requested the data from the same table, but in this case the first parameter belongs to table2 and the other two belong to table3.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. That's why you need to create the SELECT first. Does the SELECT part work as expected?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).